Is there a way to toggle develop mode for path dependencies during install?
I have a project that depends upon local libraries, which are installed as path dependencies in edit mode:
mylib = {path="../../libs/mylib", develop=true}

This is what I want during development so that library changes are immediately reflected in the project. What is the proper way to install path dependencies for production? Ideally, I'd like to be able to issue some type of flag or environment variable that forces develop mode off for all path dependencies, so that they get installed into the project's virtual environment. Barring that, I am stuck using the --no-directory flag during install, then manually copying over all libraries, which is not ideal.

This is not possible out-of-the box. For reasons and alternatives see https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/3646
Having editable path dependencies should be needed only temporary. Usually this happens in the very beginning of a project.
The way I handle this, is to add the dependency in the normal way to the project via poetry and run pip install -e /path/to/dependency afterwards.

Thanks for the guidance, the linked discussion helped. In the end I ended up building out the dependencies as wheels and installing them that way. Cheers.
